# For normed linear spaces, uniform boundedness is equivalent to equicontinuity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces, equicontinuity

In the uniform boundedness principle(the Banach-Steinhaus theorem), the domain is most generally given as an F-space(i.e. a complete quasinormed topological vector space). Here, pointwise boundedness is equivalent to uniform boundedness, which is in turn equivalent to equicontinuity.

But, for general normed linear spaces $X$ and $Y$, and for $F$ which is a collection of continuous linear maps from $X$ to $Y$, how can it be shown that uniform boundedness is equivalent to equicontinuity? I can just accept the fact intuitively and visually, but cannot move my hands to prove it mathematically with rigor. Any comment would be welcome.

Comment: If $(T_i)$ is a  collection of linear maps from $X$ to $Y$ then $(T_i)$ is uniformly bounded if there exists a finite constant $M$ such that $\|T_i\|\leq M$ for all $i$.  In this case $\|T_ix-T_iy\|=\|T_i\|\|x-y\|\leq M \|x-y\|$. Hence given $\epsilon >0$ we can take $\delta=\frac {\epsilon} {2M}$ to get  $\|T_ix-T_iy\|<\epsilon$ for all $i$ whenever $\|x-y\| <\delta$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanks!